# How can I disable / greyout specific hour in HTML time form

Tags: javascript, html, time

I have a booking form and I want to grey-out/disable those hours/times that is selected by customers already.

So that the next person book a different time. I am not quite sure how to achieve this. I have seen disable time range example but I don't know how to link it to this form and make it work. I haven't found any other useful resources around targeting this issue.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Comment: good question, I wonder if there is a timepicker plugin able to handle this issue of time slot?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not a part of the `<input type="time">` API. You can set a single `min=` and `max=` per time element, but that's more or less it.

You could, however, maybe leverage the [`setCustomValidity()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Complex_constraints_using_the_Constraint_Validation_API) to add an error message saying that the particular time chosen is reserved already if the user tries that.

(However, don't forget to validate the user's entry also on the server side. :) )

Comment: thanks for your answer. The way i am handling the booking is via phpmailer. the user fill the form in including date and time selection. and once the form is submitted it sends  the detail to my email.  and the user will be shown an alert window with an echo message.  could you please further assist / elaborate on using this api to the time form and show the error message . many thanks